# How to find all contiguous sub array combinations of an array and print it

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-programming, sub-array

I need to write a program to print all sub arrays of an array in a particular format.

```
Example-
I/o: 
n = 3
A = (1,2,3) where n is the size of the array and A is the array itself.

O/p:
(1),(2),(3)
(1),(2,3)
(1,2),(3)
(1,2,3)
```

I am able to get all subarrays using two loops but cannot produce the output in this particular order.I am coding in Java.
My code goes is as follows:-
a[]→integer Array of n elements

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  String s = "";
  for(int j=i;j<a.length;j++){
    s = s + a[j] + " ";
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

This code gives all possible sub arrays but not all contagious sub array combination that can be formed from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of hard doing without recursion. Even recursion is hard for this one because you have to loop inside the recursive method, which is rather unusual.

```java
class Main {
  static void printGroups(int[] a, int start, String output) {
    output += "(" + a[start];
    for (int i = start + 1; i < a.length; i++) {
      printGroups(a, i, output + "),");
      output += "," + a[i];
    }
    System.out.println(output + ")");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printGroups(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, 0, "");
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```text
(1),(2),(3),(4)
(1),(2),(3,4)
(1),(2,3),(4)
(1),(2,3,4)
(1,2),(3),(4)
(1,2),(3,4)
(1,2,3),(4)
(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution meets the requirements of the question, but I want to **warn** that **these are not all subset combinations**.

Missing combinations are:

```
(4,2),(3,1)
(4,1),(2,3)
(2),(1,3,4)
(3),(1,2,4)
(2),{4),(1,3)
(1),(3),(2,4)
(2),(3),(1,4)
```

Comment: do you maybe know algorithm to generate all subset combinations including these combinations?